# Principal branch of the complex logarithm does not always satisfy the product formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

My book asks to prove:

$\text{Ln}[i \cdot (-1+i)]$ does not equal to $\text{Ln}(i) + \text{Ln}(-1+i)$ where $\text{Ln}$ gives the principal log of the complex number.

I don't see why this is true though. Both sides seem to evaluate to the same value and I don't understand why they aren't equal. Could someone please give me a hand?

Comment: The wikipedia article on complex logarithms gives an example similar to the problem you have http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: @TeeJay Sorry, your right, I missed that. However, it says: $\frac{3i\pi}{2}$ doesn't equal to $\frac{-i\pi}{2}$, which I don't understand. Could you explain why this is true?

Comment: Divide out $\frac{i\pi}{2}$ from each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the principal branch, the imaginary part of Ln is always in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.  So $\text{Ln}(i) = i \pi/2$ since $\exp(i \pi/2) = i$
and $\pi/2$ is in the interval.  Similarly, $\text{Ln}(-1+i) = \ln(2)/2 + 3 \pi i/4$.  If you add these, you get $\ln(2)/2 + 5 \pi i/4$.  But this can't be a value of Ln because $5 \pi/4$ is outside the interval.

Comment: Of course, thank you.